# Applying MathML XSLT on HTML containing XML

Tags: html, xslt, transform

I have a HTML document that contains inline OMML. Is it possible to apply XSLT transformations to this inline XML somehow and get back a HTML with MathML? Probably have to use [OMML2MML.xsl](https://github.com/Versal/word2markdown/blob/master/libs/omml2mml.xsl) somehow. After that I could use mathjacx to actually render the equations for display.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<xml id="sheet1" src="OMML2MML.XSL">
    <m:oMath xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
        <m:sSub>
            <m:sSubPr>
                <m:ctrlPr>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/>
                        <w:i/>
                        <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                        <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                        <w:lang w:val="et-EE"/>
                    </w:rPr>
                </m:ctrlPr>
            </m:sSubPr>
            <m:e>
                <m:r>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/>
                        <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                        <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                        <w:lang w:val="et-EE"/>
                    </w:rPr>
                    <m:t>N</m:t>
                </m:r>
            </m:e>
            <m:sub>
                <m:r>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/>
                        <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                        <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                        <w:lang w:val="et-EE"/>
                    </w:rPr>
                    <m:t>3</m:t>
                </m:r>
            </m:sub>
        </m:sSub>
    </m:oMath>
</xml>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help!

**Ok this is what I ended up doing:**

- Got OMML from Apache POI
- Converted that to MathML with javax.xml.transform.Transformer and passing in the OMML2MML.xsl
- Removed root node namespace from MathML with plain string manipulation
- Directly injected the MathML to HTML
- Used [mathjax](http://docs.mathjax.org) to render the formulas.

Comment: Well at least in your posted sample the "HTML" is well-formed XML so you could parse the whole document with an XML parser and feed the MathML you are interested in to XSLT. But I don't know whether there can be more HTML markup like `<p id=p1>...</p>` for instance that an XML parser would not process.

Comment: Please do not edit your post to add an answer. Post it as *an answer* to your question.

Comment: @Joe As suggested by `@usr2564301`you may want to post your solution as as an `Answer` and mark it as an `Answer` so other can benefit better. In an essence you will be helping others by doing so.